# Adding two notes streams at the end of a section

Tags: notes, endnotes, bigfoot

I would like to add two streams of notes at the end of each section of a document as in the example below, i.e. one `\alph` (italicized) and another `\arabic`. I can easily insert one stream using the `endnotes` package and the command `\theendnotes` at the end of each section. I have tried using the `bigfoot` package which allows you to do something similar with footnotes, but this does not produce the required layout. I would also like the `\alph` string to be listed before the `\arabic` string. Is there a simple way of achieving this?

A simplified working example (with only one stream of notes) would look like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{}
\def\enoteheading{\par\kern1\baselineskip\kern0\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\endnote{This is note a.}
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\endnote{This is note 1.} Duis aute irure 
dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur.\endnote{This is note b.} Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
laborum.\endnote{This is note 2.}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image: Document]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to solve this problem by putting the text and a combination of footnotes and endnotes within a `minipage` (see below). This just about gives the right result, but a fundamental drawback is that `minipages` are not designed to span across pages. Ideally, the text should be allowed to do so with the notes appearing right at the end of each section.

Any other suggestion on how to resolve this problem?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{}
\def\enoteheading{\par\kern1\baselineskip\kern0\baselineskip}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\makeenmark{\hbox{\textsuperscript{\textit{\@alph{\theenmark}}}}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\footnote{This is note 1.}
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\endnote{This is note a.} Duis aute irure 
dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur.\footnote{This is note 2.} Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
laborum.\endnote{This is note b.}

\theendnotes

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]